# Recompose text after value has been changed

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

First I want to mention that this is Compose Desktop Application and not Android.

I have LogManager class which will be responsible for handling logs:

```
class LogManager {

    var log = mutableStateOf("aa")

    fun addLog(logText: String) {
        log.value += getTimeStamp() + addSpace() + logText + emptyLine()
    }

    fun printLog() {
        println(log.value)
    }

}
```

In ComposeElements class I have:

```
@Composable
fun logBox(title: String, text: MutableState<String>){
    var text:String by remember {text}
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {text = it},
        label = {Text(title)}
    )
}
```

From the main function I am creating logBox compose object:

```
logBox("log", LogManager().log)
```

Now when I update my LogManager with addLog function from any other function from other class logBox won't show it.

Example:

```
private val logManager = LogManager()

fun testMethod(text: String, something: Int) {
    logManager.addLog("Doing something: $text:$something")
}
```

So basically what I want to achieve is when I call **logManager.addLog("test")** from any non-composable function that UI is recomposed and new value is visible.

Answer (score 0):

You should not `remember` your mutable state, you should use it directly

```
@Composable
fun logBox(title: String, text: MutableState<String>) {
    TextField(
        value = text.value,
        onValueChange = {text.value = it },
        label = {Text(title)}
    )
}
```

but a better solution would be to not accept a mutable state and let the caller handle the update

```
@Composable
fun logBox(title: String, text: String, onValueChange: (String) -> Unit) {
    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        label = {Text(title)}
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried it and it seems like the logBox is still not recomposing after logManager.addLog("test") is called and it's always showing its default value "aa".